# What dinosaurs live during cretaceous period?

Tags: dinosaurs

I cant find website that shows all dinosaurs that lived during this time?

Tyrannosaur rex and triceratops I know but what else?

Answer (score 4):

Wikipedia has a nice summary: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Cretaceous_dinosaurs

Comment: cant you make list of them that lived with tyrannosaur rex please

Answer (score 1):

To see which dinosaurs lived alongside Tyrannosaurus I suggest you browse the dinosaurs list here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hell_Creek_Formation#Dinosaurs , as T-rex was found in the Hell Creek Formation. It might not be a complete list but it is the best I know.